# Why soundEffectsEnabled=false does not work in a recylerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to disable all sound effects especially when an item is focused but nothing has been successful.

I tried setting

```
<item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">false</item>
```

in the main app theme, the RecyclerView and RecyclerView items but sound effects still work. I previously used a ListView and sound effects were disabled properly with this option (probably because it uses a `selected` property instead of relying on focus).

I could also disable system sounds entirely by calling `mAudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0)` but this does not work with devices that implement a fixed volume policy.

Steps to reproduce:

1. use a RecyclerView with a basic adapter
2. Make items focusable
3. Navigate using keyboard keys UP/DOWN or LEFT/RIGHT in the emulator

You will hear sound effects even when setting `soundEffectsEnabled` to false

**Update:**
A sample app with a basic RecyclerView to reproduce the problem

https://github.com/gloriousmce/recycler-view-issue